# Auth fails on Windows XP with git and tortoisegit

Tags: windows, git, ssh-keys, openssh, tortoisegit

My authentication keeps failing.  I've created my SSH keys and the public key has been imported by the local git admin, but I still get prompted for a password:

```
git.exe clone  --progress -v  "git@repo:project.git" "C:\web\project"  
Cloning into C:\web\project...  
git@repo's password:  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

- My SSH keys are passphraseless and live under "`C:\Documents and Settings\username\.ssh`" and I also copied them to "`C:\Documents and Settings\username\ssh`" (without the preceding dot) just for good measure.
- In the Windows environment variables screen, the `HOME` system var is set to the correct directory for my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `ssh -vvv git@repo` returns?

As long as this ssh request doesn't work, no git operation will work with the `git@repo` server.
And if the ssh reports it is does try to offer the publickey, then you must double-check it has been correctly added to the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the repo server.

Here is an extract of example of a ssh session which works:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /p/.ssh/mypubkey
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp f8:d9:7...:cf

debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Two comments:

- My `%HOME%` reference not `%HOMEDIR%` but a custom drive (`p:\`), this is a local convention at work and might not apply to you.
- the names of my public/private keys don't follow the default standard (`id_rsa.pub`/`id_rsa`)

I have added a `config` file in the `%HOME%\.ssh` directory in order to name explicitly the public key file:

```
host gitrepo
     user git
     hostname repo
     identityfile ~/.ssh/mypubkey
```

That way, I can simply type: `ssh gitrepo`, and ssh will know which user, hostname and exact full path of the public key to use.