# How do I tell 'git tag -s ..' (or -u) where my private key is (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows, git

I successfully put my private key at a place where git finds it when it connects to github.
(like this https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key/198691#198691 )

But when I try to sign a tag, this default magic seems not to apply. The brilliant [git community book talks](http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/3_git_tag.html) about an `gpg-key-id`, but I created my keys with puttygen, and seem not to have such an id.

So, how can I tell git a Windows machine that the key it shall use resides at ~/.ssh/id_rsa ?

Thank you, Falko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sign a tag you need a GPG/PGP ID and not a SSH id. The SSH id is used to encrypt the connection and identify yourself to the server.

The GPG works in general similar how ever there is a kind of "profile" linked to your public gpg key. To get started on with GPG on windows [gpg3win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) is a good place to look. Also the Wikipedia entries on [GPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) and [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgp) are good places to get some insight regarding this topic.

Comment: Ah, so my current key just doesn't fit the bill to sign. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I tell git a Windows machine that the key it shall use resides at ~/.ssh/id_rsa

You need to define `~`, ie `HOME` (which isn't a variable defined by default on Windows. `HOMEPATH` or `USERPROFILE` are).
See for instance "[Auth fails on Windows XP with git and tortoisegit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318590/auth-fails-on-windows-xp-with-git-and-tortoisegit/5322335#5322335)", where `HOME` is defined to a complete non-default path (ie not `HOMEPATH`)