# git bash asks for password when trying to pull or fetch.

Tags: git, putty

I have received ssh-2 key which I then converted to SSH-1 through puttygen. I load it every time I make pull or fetch with Tortoise git GUI and it doesn't ask me a password. But I want to use git bash instead, when I try to pull or fetch with git bash it asks for password. So I guess I need to load that key for git bash too or disable password protection at all. Can you help, please?

Comment: SSH-1 is _significantly_ less secure than SSH-2. Unless you are in some horribly broken/outdated environment, you should _never_ use SSH-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[TortoiseGit with openssh key not authenticating using ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13524792/6309)" (which is the opposite of your case: TortoiseGit doesn't work, while the git bash does work), make sure of the value of your `HOME` environment variable.

Windows itself doesn't define HOME, and you need to have it referring to a directory which includes `.ssh/...`.

So check out the value of HOME in the TortoiseGit settings, and make sure to set your HOME in your git bash session for any ssh-related operation to work.

Answer (score 1):

When working over linux, you have to put your ssh key on the .ssh folder on your home directory.

Said that, the git 'clones' that work over windows just emulate this behavior, designing a given directory as your home, and expect the ssh-key to be in `HOME\.ssh`, in a file named `id_rsa` (just as it would be in a Linux enviroment).

Anyway, I'm not a Windows user, so I'm not in a good position to explain what you should do, but [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key) is a very informative question made in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) which haves a good explanation of the setup in the accepted answer.