# Windows 8.1 Git SSH

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I know that the use of Git and SSH has been asked many times and answered, however, here is my problem.

I have the dreaded 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent'.  I understand how the ssh-agent works and it uses a socket file to communicate.  If you do not specify the file ssh-agent uses **/tmp/ssh-xxxxxxx/agent.pid** as the default.  With Windows 8.1 you can not create files in the main drive so Windows will put a redirect into **C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Temp** and put the file there.  These are bieng created.

When I call **eval $(ssh-agent)** within Bash the agent is started as a separate process. I create the appropriate environment variables (SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SSH_AGENT_PID) in my Git Bash environment.  When I call ssh-add it fails.

To test my understanding I have used a file within my User Directory by calling **ssh-agent -a 'c:/Users/userid/Temp/socket'** and set the environment variables correctly.  Again it fails.

I then started the agent in debug mode **ssh-agent -da 'c:/Users/userid/Temp/socket'** which did not fork a process as expected.  I then went to a Windows cmd prompt and set the environment variables.  I then entered **ssh-add**, it worked, I was asked for the pass phrase for my private key.

My question is: Does anyone know why the background process is not picking up the ssh-add?

A few things have come to mind:

1. The background process is using a different user id and thus can not have access to the socket file.
2. The background process is not getting it environment variables set correctly.

I believe this is a Windows problem rather than an ssh one.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the ssh-agent coming with Git for Windows? Do you see the same issue with the latest Git for Windows? (the 2.4.2.1: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: I am using Git-1.9.5-preview20150319 from https://git-scm.com/download/win.  It looks like there is a newer version.  Would you recommend I switch?

Comment: Just tried it with suggested version, same thing happens

Comment: Do you have a `$HOME/.bashrc` in your git-for-windows bash session? (as in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshoot+SSH+Issues#TroubleshootSSHIssues-Couldnotopenaconnectiontoyourauthenticationagent)

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/14913230/6309?

Comment: The other alternative would be to substitute ssh-agent with pageant: https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/issues/697#issuecomment-5530167

Comment: Make sure GIT_SSH isn't already set (and pointing to, for instance, pageant while you are trying to use ssh_agent)

Comment: Thanks VonC.Git for Windows is quite different than Git-1.9.5.preview20150319 and I could not find an sensible documentation.  To answer your other questions: 1. I have been follwoing the instructions for  [confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET)  2. I looked at [stackoverflow.com/a/14913230/6309](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14913230/6309), not sure it helps.  3. I will look at pagaent.