# How to use linux generated keys on windows with tortoise git?

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh-keys

I have git working on a Linux host with a set of keys in the .ssh folder.
id_rsa and id_rsa.pub

I want to use those same keys from the Linux host in my virtual windows 8.1 machine.
How / where do I need to copy/edit /massage those Linux keys so that Tortoise git can use them?

I only ever see puttygen being advertised and described as the way to generate keys but what if other keys need to be used?

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question would be better served if asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to copy your public/private `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub/id_rsa` keys into `%USERPROFILE\.ssh`.
Note that copying a *private* key is not the best practice though: generating a new pair of keys, and registering a new public key would be best.

Then you need to configure TortoiseGit to look for openssh keys, and not putty keys: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33328628/6309) in TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Network.

Since TortoiseGit is configured by default for using putty, the [OP berntd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9222013/berntd) chose the other route ([see comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273189/how-to-use-linux-generated-keys-on-windows-with-tortoise-git/48274684#comment83612340_48274684)):

> I imported the `id_rsa` key into puTTYgen under convert.
>   I then saved it in the `.ppk` format.
>   I then told Tortoisegit to use putty key by ticking the box in the clone window.
>   It worked!

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand the second part where you say I need to configure TortoiseGit to look for openssh keys. I see the box but under network but it has: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe in it and there is no ssh.exe anywhere in the bin directory.     (how do I get a newline in this editor? pressing enter posts the comment)

Comment: @berntd the Git in this image is a bit old: you will find ssh.exe in your Git installation folder, under `usr\bin\` subfolder.

Comment: @berntd And yes, I requested newlines in comments 8+ years ago (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/6309)... I wouldn't hold my breath though.

Comment: Thanks. I found that now. While waiting for a reply, I came up with another way to get this going. I imported the rsa_id key into puTTYgen under convert. I then saved it in the .ppk format. I then told Tortoisegit to use putty key by ticking the box in the clone window.  It worked!

Comment: @berntd Great! I have included your comment in the answer for ore visibilty.